# Building a D flip-flop with two D inputs using 3 S-R latches

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, latch

"Use three clocked SR latches to build a D flip-flop with two D inputs (D1 and D2 ) and two clock inputs C1 and C2 . Clock C1 takes data D1 and clock C2 takes data D2 ."

Any hints how to start?

Comment: Think about it.

Comment: Stackexchange frowns upon posting homework questions without providing any evidence you've tried to do it on your own first. And this looks very much like a homework question.

Comment: Start drawing truth tables.

Answer (score 0):

How to start:

Look up "Clocked SR latch" and understand it.

Look up "D type flip flop" and understand it.

Read the question which asks for an implementation which has 4 inputs D1,D2,C1,C2 and two outputs Q1 and Q2 which outputs the state of D1 on Q1 when C1 is pulsed and the state of D2 on Q2 when C2 is pulsed - all this made from 3 clocked SR latches.

Get a pencil, paper, rubber and start drawing...

Comment: Who said anything about two outputs?

Comment: Ok. So i need one S-R latch to implement a D flip flop. I have two outputs Q1, Q2 so i need two S-R latches. Then why problem asked to use 3 of them?

Comment: @ Dave Tweed, that's what I interpreted "Clock C1 takes data D1 and clock C2 takes data D2" as. What else does it mean?

Comment: @ Ju Bc - an SR latch has 2 data inputs (S and R -> S = R = 1 is not allowed) a D Type has one (Data) which can be high or low . Converting your  data signals to drive the S and R lines is probably what this question is all about...

Comment: @TimMottram - I interpret it as single output Q, which is updated to D1 on transistion of clock C1 and D2 on transition of clock C2, i.e. it shows the appropriate data for whichever clock happened most recently. i.e. equivalent to the verilog `reg q; always @(posedge c1) q <= d1; always @(posedge c2) q <= d2;`.